# How do i set fractional part of 2 digits in my editText?

Tags: android

I am using filter to set the length of editText.
I set EditText length as 10 as per following.

```
TextView editVew = new TextView(R.id.txtAmt);
InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10);
editVew.setFilters(FilterArray);
editVew.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

My confusion : how to set fraction of 2 digits in my number and total length of my editview should not exceed 10 digits ?
If any body knows please reply.
Thanks

Comment: "What i am confusing is how to set fraction of 2 digits in my number" Huh?

Comment: Modyfy your filter to achive this-

(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357455/limit-decimal-places-in-android-edittext)

Answer (score 1):

Try this to make your edittext support two digits after decimals.

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAmt);
text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
{
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable edittext) 
    {
        String str= edittext.toString();
        int posDot = str.indexOf(".");
        if (posDot <= 0) return;
        if (str.length() - posDot - 1 > 2)
        {
            edt.delete(posDot + 3, posDot + 4);
        }
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}
});
```

And use `android:maxLength="10"` in xml to restrict your editText support 10 maximmum input digits

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
            maxLength = 10;
            smsType = "free";
            FilterArraySeventy[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
            message.setFilters(FilterArrayten);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for your Answer

```
amountEditText.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
    amountEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(!s.toString().matches("^\\$(\\d{1,3}(\\,\\d{3})*|(\\d+))(\\.\\d{2})?$"))
            {
                String userInput= ""+s.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
                StringBuilder cashAmountBuilder = new StringBuilder(userInput);

                while (cashAmountBuilder.length() > 3 && cashAmountBuilder.charAt(0) == '0') {
                    cashAmountBuilder.deleteCharAt(0);
                }
                while (cashAmountBuilder.length() < 3) {
                    cashAmountBuilder.insert(0, '0');
                }
                cashAmountBuilder.insert(cashAmountBuilder.length()-2, '.');
                cashAmountBuilder.insert(0, '$');

                amountEditText.setText(cashAmountBuilder.toString());
                // keeps the cursor always to the right
                Selection.setSelection(amountEditText.getText(), cashAmountBuilder.toString().length());

            }

        }
    });
```

Same Question discussed here

[Ref Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636444/edittext-showing-numbers-with-2-decimals-at-all-times)